# Smarty foreach list - increment index

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach, smarty

How i can show  two different elements in a list(`<li>`) in foreach loop in each iteration?

For example, i have:

```
$arr = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd','e','f');
```

and I want to show like this:

```
- a-c-e
- b-d-f

<ul>
{foreach from=$products item=product name=products key=spi}
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
{/foreach}
</ul>
```

this is an example, I am working on prestashop, so I want to do this:

[image: view li]

[image: Code]

Answer (score 0):

The solution using `range`, `array_intersect_key`, `array_flip` and `implode` functions:

```
$arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd','e','f'];
$products = [
    implode('-', array_intersect_key($arr, array_flip(range(0, 5, 2)))),
    implode('-', array_intersect_key($arr, array_flip(range(1, 5, 2))))
];
```

Now, `$products` contains the following array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => a-c-e
    [1] => b-d-f
)
```

Traversing `$products` within a Twig template:

```
<ul>
    {% for p in products %}
        <li>{{ p }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: thank for your reply, i am very confused, i edited my post, please can you see it again?

Comment: @SaulRamos, there's a lot of extra code on those screenshots you have posted, which doesn't directly relate to your initial question code. Make some efforts, start with simple traversing, then, if worked, you can go with some extra code if needed